# Install a smaller new disk from a big Time Machine backup

Tags: time-machine

i have a MacBook Pro (2012) with a 500GB hard drive.

I would like to install a 250GB SDD drive and i want to reinstall via Time Machine.

The problem is obvious : my Time Capsule contains more than 250GB data.

Will it prevent me from installing or will it allow me to choose what to take or not take ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you intend to do with the data which doesn't fit onto the SSD?

Comment: I would like to easily install the system on my new disk. After the installation I would plug the old hard drive in a dock to have access to the data that was not migrated.

Comment: well i have removed data from the old drive, and used Carbon Copy Cloner to create my new disk with Restoration partition .. it ran great